# Type inference error when creating a React Context

Tags: typescript, types, react-context

I'm trying to create simple context provider in a project that uses TypeScript, typed as such:

```
import { createContext } from 'react';

export type ContextType = {
  foo: boolean,
};

export const FooContext: React.Context<ContextType> = createContext({
  foo: true,
});
```

It looks simple enough, but on `FooContext` TypeScript is telling me that `Type 'Context<{ loading: true; }>' is not assignable to type 'Context<ContextType>'.` becasuse `Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'true'`.

Casting `foo: true as boolean` fixes the issue, but I think it's strange that that's even necessary.

Is there any other way to do this correctly without getting any type errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass your context type as a type parameter instead:

```
export const FooContext = createContext<ContextType>({
    foo: true,
});
```

`FooContext` will be *inferred* to be the type `React.Context<ContextType>`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYygUwIYzQYQgO2wA94BfOAMyghDgCJ0NkY6BuAKHbSMljhgCeYNHDyFuMACpCRAXkTs4SyhAgAuOACNVAG0z4OpDlx7R4yAgGd4AMVVji8eakzYHEgDzuS04QD4ACgRFZQpVDRgoAFc0ABp2UgBKDiA)